# Active record store for sessions with multi uploader (uploadify, plupload) with Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, uploadify, multifile-uploader, plupload

Is possible to integrate some **multifile uploader** (like plupload, uploadify) with active records store for *sessions* in **Ruby on Rails 3**?

I just found only cookie store examples.

Comment: I wrote this yesterday: https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Rails-setup-for-V5

Comment: I'd really stick with this flash-free solution.

Answer (score 1):

```
Uploader::Application.config.session_store :active_record_store, :key => '_uploader_session'

Rails.application.config.middleware.insert_before(
  Rails.application.config.session_store,
  FlashSessionCookieMiddleware,
  Rails.application.config.session_options[:key]
)
```

I hope this is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I actually wouldn't stick with the flash-free solution.  I encountered security issues in IE.  Uploadify (the flash-version) was way easier to implement on the client-side.  Yes, using a 3rd-party plugin sucks but in this case I'd stick with it.